# What URL can I hit to initiate call?

Tags: calls, google-account, automation, cloud

I'd like to be able to hit a URL with CURL from my laptop, and have it cause my android phone to initiate a phone call, on speakerphone if possible.

I'm using a Linux laptop with Firefox browser, and I have tel: links set to run a bash script.

I'd like my script to send a GET/POST to some google cloud API which subsequently sends a command from the cloud to my phone that causes my phone to initiate a phone call hands-free to a number I send in the GET/POST.

I will use this to make tel links clickable in my laptop's browser.  Browsing on android sucks.  Calling from a "hangouts tab" in the laptop sucks.  Combining in this way will avoid the most things that suck, which is my new years resolution.

I may also use this to automate calls to appointments/meetings that I need to attend.  i.e. at the correct time, my phone simply auto-joins whatever zoom meeting, without me having to remember it.  Bonus points if this API can also, optionally begin the call on mute.

Comment: [Chrome browser supports this natively](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9430554?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop). Otherwise, I don't think there's network-based API to initiate a call on stock Android (without 3rd-party apps/API).

Comment: So.  Chrome browser doesn't use a network-based API to do this?  Must be sorcery I guess.  That aside, changing the browser I use every day, have for years, and depend on, doesn't solve this even if that path of destruction wasn't important.  It doesn't address scheduled call initiations, which I could trivially put in a cron job with an API.

Comment: Looks like it uses their internal push notification service [between Chrome desktop to Chrome mobile](https://www.androidauthority.com/send-phone-numbers-from-chrome-to-android-1039405/).